# enable to Send image as Fileoutputstream via resteasy

Tags: java, image, rest, resteasy, fileoutputstream

In my server side i have an image that will be sended via rest to the client side
After sending, the image should be deleted.

So the image will be coppied on a fileoutputstream and i send the  fileoutputstream to the client side and i delete the image.

i use the following code:

```
@GET
@Path("/get_image")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM })    
public Response getImage(){

.......

    File image = new File("myimage.png");
    FileOutputStream oos = new FileOutputStream("imageToSend.png");
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(image);
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
                oos.write(buf, 0, c);
                oos.flush();
            }

            ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(oos);
            response.header("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=image.png");
            oos.close();
            is.close();

            image.delete();

            return response.build();
        }
    }
```

but when i execute the getImage method i found this error

```
org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: java.io.FileOutputStream of media type: application/octet-stream
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:67)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:411)
```

If any one have idea about the cause of this problem....

kind regards

Comment: What do you expect Resteasy to do with an output stream? It can't read from it, and there's no interface to get the file which the stream represents.

Comment: @Kenster, i would like to delete an image after it is sent:

`File image = new File(pathImage);
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object)image);
response.header("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=tsunami_image.png");
image.delete()
return response.build();`

if i set the image object in the response and i delete the image, i got **fileNotFoundExeption** error. then according to my research on the net, they advise to write directly the output stream in response and then you can delete the file. But I have not been able to make this ....

Comment: Maybe you could share some of this research you found about passing output streams to resteasy.

Comment: @Kenster  
for exemple in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930127/how-to-delete-file-after-rest-response, they advise to use output stream –

Answer (score 2):

You should either just use the `InputStream` as the response body (RESTeasy will do the writing for you), or you can use `StreamingOutput` to write the data straight to the response stream. For example

```
StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {
    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(image);
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = is.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) {
            oos.write(buf, 0, c);
            oos.flush();
        }
        is.close();
    }
}

ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(output);
```

It may just be easier to use return the `InputStream` instead. It pretty much does the same thing under the hood, as using the `StreamingOutput` like above. One odd thing I've faced in the past is with large files, when trying to return `InputStream`. With `StreamingOutput`, it seemed to work better.